# Python merge dictionaries based on value

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I have two dictionaries (Python), which I am merging based on the value (not key). However, my approach is very inefficient, essentially O(n^2). Is there a better way to go about it?

The dictionary in this case is essentially an integer key, the value is a tuple (5 elements long), all integers.

thanks!

Example:

Dictionary A: `{25: (1, 5, 1, 5), 34: (5, 24, 5, 24)}`

Dictionary B: `{46: (1, 5, 1, 5), 29: (5, 23, 1, 5)}`.

The merged dictionary is: `{25: (1, 5, 1, 5), 34: (5, 24, 5, 24), 29: (5, 23, 1, 5)}`. Note that the first element of dictionary A has same value tuple of first element of dictionary B therefore, we only select one

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit about this "value merging"? For instance you could post two example dictionaries and the desired result for the merged dictinoary. Is there a bijection between keys and values?

Comment: Sure, Dictionary A: {25: 1, 5, 1, 5}, {34: 5, 24, 5, 24} Dictionary B: {46: 1, 5, 1, 5}, {29: 5, 23, 1, 5}. The merged dictionary will be:  {25: 1, 5, 1, 5}, {34: 5, 24, 5, 24}, {29: 5, 23, 1, 5}. Note that the first element of dictionary A has same value tuple of first element of dictionary B therefore, we only select one.

Comment: @OP, better edit your question and don't add comments.

Comment: @OP `A: {25: 1, 5, 1, 5}` is not a dictionary. Did you maybe mean `A = {25: (1, 5, 1, 5) }`?

Comment: @OP: On which basis do you decide whether to keep key `25` or key `46`?

Comment: I just used the first dictionary i.e. 25, but the order does not really matter as long as it is consistent

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```
a = {25: (1, 5, 1, 5), 34: (5, 24, 5, 24)}
b = {46: (1, 5, 1, 5), 29: (5, 23, 1, 5)}

for k, v in b.items ():
    if v not in a.values (): a [k] = v

print (a)
```

But I guess it is still O(n**2).

EDIT:
This should be faster for large dictionaries:

```
c = {}
for k, v in a.items (): c [v] = k
for k, v in b.items (): c [v] = k

c = dict ( (b, a) for a, b in c.items () )
print (c)
```

Comment: Also, please use `a.iteritems()` to avoid creating a new list of the items in the dict.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

A = {25: (1, 5, 1, 5), 34: (5, 24, 5, 24)}
B = {46: (1, 5, 1, 5), 29: (5, 23, 1, 5)}

vk = defaultdict(list)
sources = A, B
for source in sources:
    for k,v in source.iteritems():
        vk[v].append(k)

out = {v[0]:k for k,v in vk.iteritems()}
```

which will always take the earliest key in `sources`, and produces

```
>>> out
{25: (1, 5, 1, 5), 34: (5, 24, 5, 24), 29: (5, 23, 1, 5)}
```

If memory were a concern you could change the `vk[v].append(k)` line; right now it builds up an intermediate structure that's not needed, but I'm not entirely certain what the right selection logic in the case of collisions should be.

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is

```
C={v:k for k,v in {v:k for k, v in B.items()+A.items()}.iteritems()}
```

..which is compact code, and maybe only as expensive as `O(n*log(n))`, because all what's done is inserting in dictionaries.